# HTTP request with requests in python returning text instead of json

Tags: python, python-requests, mashape

```
def thready(name,count):
    payload={'Accept': 'application/json;charset=utf-8', 'X-Mashape-Key': 'key'

            }


    link = "https://montanaflynn-gender-guesser.p.mashape.com/?name=" + name
    r=requests.get(link ,headers=payload)
    print r.headers
    data=r.json()

    print data


count=0

thready("bob",count)
```

So I just tried to do a simple HTTP request in python. In the r.header i get

```
{'date': 'Wed, 22 Jul 2015 06:30:12 GMT', 'content-length': '178', 'content-type
': 'text/html', 'connection': 'keep-alive', 'server': 'Mashape/5.0.6'}
```

In the header I said it should return json. The return is text though? Very confused about this fact? Some insight would be very helpful because I'm trying to do the simple

Comment: And what is your problem? As a result you gets JSON in string representation.

Comment: How do I work with it like a dictionary?

Comment: it is already a dictionary, but if you print the entire dict, it will look on the console almost like json. Just try `print data['message']`

Comment: I cant even get paste the line of data

Traceback (most recent call last):
ValueError: No JSON object could be decoded

Comment: You should have written that fact in the question ;) For me the snippet works. Could you do `print r.text` and paste it here?

Comment: Yes, when I look at r.text it seems to be just a body of javascript and html. Im messing up something here, not sure what.

Comment: Ah, this sounds like a DoS-preventing captcha from an upstream Content Delivery Network like Incapsula, CloudFlare or Akamai. I guess you've sent to many requests to this endpoint and it is rate-limited, or your IP is now blocked, ... Try to save the result in an html file and open it in your browser.

Comment: If this is the root cause - waiting might solve it, or a proxy/tunnel ;-)

Comment: Seems the html page is a page not found error. This is really strange.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with the code.

I have inspected your API request upstream by going to the source: the  API provider's page and it looks like the API is defunct/not working as expected.
Which is exactly why you're getting errors.
Solution:
1) Contact the provider to try to resolve the problem, its on them not on you to fix it
2) Find an alternative API from the same portal: https://www.mashape.com/explore?query=gender

Good luck

Comment: Thank you, seems like it something on their side.